# hive jdbc driver: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to output second root, <r>

Tags: c#, jdbc, hive, dundas

I am using the Hive JDBC 3.1 driver (from Hortontworks or official, I have the same issues) in a c# application (Dundas) and I get the error:

> hive jdbc driver: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to output second root,

I really cannot say much more, as the java stack trace is swallowed, and Dundas is a third party application which I did not develop and is not open source. It does use the JDBC driver to connect to hive (the odbc driver is not an option as it is utterly bugged) hence the java stack trace in a C# application (and yes I am talking to support as well, but I was hoping that someone else encountered (and fixed!) the same issue).

Using the driver standalone, via a Java standalone class works fine.

The connection from Dundas works fine, it is getting data that fails.

Any idea what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Is this a C# or Java question? Because if it's Java it's missing the Tag, and if it's C# then why do you have a Java "XMLStreamException" and the jdbc Tag?

Comment: @MindSwipe I edited the question to make this more clear. It is a C# app (so c# tag), using a jdbc driver (so no actual java tag). I am aware that my question is a long shot. I am utterly flabbergasted and having no control over the app itself, I sadly cannot tinker much but I hoped to find someone having gone through the same issues.

Comment: Could you link the driver you're using? All I can find when googling something along the lines of "Using jdbc driver with C#" is people stating that jdbc stands for "Java DataBase Connection" and that it cannot be used with C#

Comment: The driver is the official hive driver: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/3.1.0/hive-jdbc-3.1.0-standalone.jar Dundas has to use some kind of bridge, but as I said, it's closed source so I cannot say much more. Using the MySQL JDBC driver from Dundas works, so the JDBC bridge is possible and works in some case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was a bug in Dundas - but they managed to fix it. The fix should ship after version 6.0.